# My program is not recognizing its using a negative number

Tags: python-3.x

I just started programming for school and this assignment requires me to enter a number and then use it to count from 0 up to the number, then choose a math operation, and then use that math operation.

The problem occurs when I enter a negative number, it gives me the correct message "Too small - Try again: " . but once I enter a positive number it still assigns my original negative number to the program.

Here is my noobie code:

```
num1 = int(input("\nEnter a number 1 or greater:\t"))
counting = num1 + 1


def count():
        print("Counting from 0 to", num1,":")
        for i in range(0,counting):
                print(i, end = ' ')
        math_op()


def reset():
        num1 = int(input("Too small - Try again: "))
        if num1 <= 0:
                reset()
        else:
                count() 

def math_op():

        ops = input("\n\nChoose math operation (+, -, *)")

        if ops in ('+'):
                print("Table for",num1,"using +:")
                for i in range(1,11):
                        print(num1 ,'+', i ,'=', num1 + i)                


        if ops in ('-'):
                print("Table for",num1,"using -:")
                for i in range(1,11):
                        print(num1 ,'-', i ,'=', num1 - i)              

        if ops in ('*'):
                print("Table for",num1,"using *:")
                for i in range(1,11):
                        print(num1 ,'*', i ,'=', num1 * i)                

if num1 <= 0:
        reset()
else:
        count()
```

Comment: Why would it ask you for a new number? Your code isn't in a loop.

Comment: Do I use a while loop here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're missing a `while` loop:

```
num1 = -1
while num1 < 1:
    num1 = int(input("\nEnter a number 1 or greater:\t"))

# remaining code after here
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something along these lines.

Answer (score 0):

you never set the number to count when the correction is positive:

```
def reset():
    num1 = int(input("Too small - Try again: "))
    if num1 <= 0:
        reset()
    else:
        counting = num1 + 1
        count()
```